# can I ask a question of the safe ways to pick a prostitute

Tags: discussion

can I ask a question of the safe ways to pick a prostitute when traveling into a tourist country ?. for example is it ok to ask the hotel for such things ? if not are there any other places ? concerning the theft or maybe the pimps who ask lot of money or maybe they deceive the tourrists . can I ask something related to that ?

Answer (score 6):

Nothing in our official guidance about [permitted topics](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explicitly excludes questions about prostitution, any more than about any other topic that some might find objectionable, like travel for game hunting, or drug tourism, or visiting Antarctica, or voluntourism. In fact, there is a tag for [sex](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) and an old question about [shopping Amsterdam's red light district](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3625), although it would probably be considered too broad as written if asked today.

Regardless of the topic, the question needs to be phrased in a way that is [answerable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the StackExchange question-and-answer format: it should be about a real problem (no hypotheticals), should demonstrate initial attempts at research (i.e. not answerable with a quick search of the web or a guidebook), and should be closed-ended (not answered with an opinion/review or a list).

As you have phrased the question, I would not consider it suitable— not because it is about prostitution per se, but because it is too broad. There is huge variation [even within Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_in_Europe), for example. Regardless of the topic, it is almost always safer on this site to ask about a specific locale.

You also ask about too many aspects at once. It would be better to start with a single, straightforward question, then submit new, separate questions as needed. This gives you the space to establish *characteristics* of what you consider to be "safe," "inexpensive," etc., and not simply ask for *characterizations*, which are impossible to answer because there is so much variation from person to person when it comes to standards of cost and hygiene and so on.

Finally, note that "shopping" questions tend to be frowned upon [throughout StackExchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and this site is no exception.

Comment: Does it make any difference in your opinion if the question is asking about a location where this is legal vs somewhere where it is illegal?

Comment: @MartinSmith As others have [noted elsewhere](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/3804/1480), legal and illegal are not always binary— especially for something like prostitution, which was technically illegal in the Netherlands until 2000, but officially tolerated in certain forms in certain areas. Asking about something illegal but tolerated locally is more likely to be accepted whereas asking about circumventing a law that reflects local culture and mores (or is intended to address a local social problem) will be more skeptically treated.